# setting fields of an object contained in an array in for-loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I query a websql database and some of the fields returned have the string-value "undefined".

In a loop, I want to check if the fields have undefined and if so, assign them an empty string as a value.

All works well, except for the assignment. Here's my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    for (temp in result[i]) {
        if (result[i][temp] == "undefined") {
            console.log(typeof(result[i][temp])); // outputs "string" as it should
            result[i][temp] = "";
        }
    }
}
```

result is an array that contains objects. The code in the if-block is executed except for the assignment, which never takes effect.

What do I need to change?

EDIT:

When I add this immediately after the loop above , it outputs "undefined" for each field that already was undefined before the loop above (hope that makes sense :D).

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    for (temp in result[i]) {
        if (result[i][temp] == "undefined") {
            console.log(result[i][temp]);
        }
    }
}
```

I use the whole thing in a callback function, but that shouldnt matter, right? I mean inside a callback function, the code is executed in order just like anywhere else, right?

2nd EDIT:

```
                    var arr = [];
                    arr.push(result[0]); // result currently only holds one object

                    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        for (temp in arr[i]) {
                            console.log(arr[i][temp]);
                            console.log(typeof(arr[i][temp])); // outputs "string" for the undefined fields
                            if (arr[i][temp] == "undefined") {
                                arr[i][temp] = "szszsz";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        for (temp in arr[i]) {
                            console.log(arr[i][temp]); // still outputs undefined
                        }
                    }
```

ANSWER:

See ArinCool's comment: I copied the array into another array and then I was able to overwrite the fields.

Comment: If I test this code in chrome, it works. The result array is updated just as you'd expect. If you output the result as a whole after running this, it shows no changes for you?

Comment: thanx for the reply, see my edit. I also use chrome by the way.

Comment: Your code should work provided the result array is populated correctly. Are you sure that the values returned are `"undefined"` instead of just `undefined`?

Comment: These result objects don't have readonly properties, do they?

Comment: @ArinCool: I populate a table with those fields and the values appear as strings in the table, as "undefined". And I do the typecheck and it says type = string, so it really is "undefined". I thought it was undefined too, at first, but no.

Comment: And @Bergi: How can I check that?

Comment: Can you try populating a new array object from the retrieved object and see if the new array has the same issues?

Comment: I was actually thinking of populating `arr` array within the `for` loop rather than populating it before the loop.

Comment: it worked now! I can overwrite the fields! Thanx a lot! Why did it work now?